# How to get the current time in the format `2010-12-20 06:32:48` with PHP?

Tags: php, time

Anyone knows how to do it?

What I know is `time()` but it's pure digits..

Comment: [Googling](http://www.google.de/#hl=de&expIds=17259,24283&xhr=t&q=php+format+date&cp=11&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=php+format+&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=9518358c6ae80f89) brings up http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 4):

As you've said, you can get the current timestamp via the [time function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php). You can then pass this timestamp to PHP's [date function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). (It'll use the current time if no timestamp is provided.)

The specific format you're after is:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a formatted date/timestamp use the `date()` function

```
$dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```